# pipenv environment on Intel's Distribution for Python

Tags: python, pipenv

I am trying to take advantage of MKL (Intel Math Kernel Library) in my Python application which is using pipenv for package management and virtual environment.

I have Intel's Distribution for Python installed:

```
$ /opt/intel/intelpython3/bin/python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Intel Corporation
```

Now I am trying to install a new pipenv environment using this Python distribution:

```
/home/.../test4 $ which pipenv
/home/.../.local/bin/pipenv

/home/.../test4 $ pipenv install --python=/opt/intel/intelpython3/bin/python
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/.../test4/Pipfile
Using /opt/intel/intelpython3/bin/python (3.6.5) to create virtualenv...
⠋Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/intel/intelpython3/bin/python
Using base prefix '/opt/intel/intelpython3'
New python executable in /home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/test4-qDBSlh47/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Setting project for test4-qDBSlh47 to /home/.../test4

Virtualenv location: /home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/test4-qDBSlh47
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Updated Pipfile.lock (ca72e7)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (ca72e7)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.

/home/.../test4 $ pipenv run python --version
Python 3.6.6
```

As you see the python version within this `pipenv` environment is NOT the one which was used to create the `pipenv` with its `--python` argument.

It should be `Python 3.6.5 :: Intel Corporation`, but it is `Python 3.6.6`.

`Python 3.6.6` is my system `python3.6`:

```
$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.6
$ which python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6
```

So the question is why pipenv's `--python` argument does not drive what python executable gets copied into the virtual env. If that is not the way to set the python executable inside the virtual env, then what is?

**EDIT:**
The generated Pipfile:

```
$ vi Pipfile

[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Comment: What does your pipfile say?

Comment: Added the content of Pipfile

Comment: The Python used by `pipenv` can be found with `pipenv --py` in your project folder. If `\`pipenv --py\` --version` is Python 3.6.6, there is a problem with `pipenv`. If it's `Python 3.6.5 :: Intel Corporation`, you may have a problem with your `$PATH`, maybe open a new terminal and enter `pipenv shell`. From within `pipenv shell`, check `echo $PATH`.